# Force region when serializing dates to JSON from NSDicitionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I am initializing an AFJSONRequestOperation (using the AFNetworking libraries) with a request that contains date fields.  When the endpoint receives the request, the date is formatted in the region of the device.  For example:

```
"last_update" = "dom dic 1 10:57:52 -0500 2013";
```

I would like to force the formatting to a region such as Canada or the US.

Is this possible as our endpoint is choking on dates that are not formatted with English such as:

```
"last_update" = "Wed Dec 1 10:57:52 -0500 2013";
```

Comment: IMO you should not use any language at all. instead something like `@"2013-12-01T10:57:52-0500"` http://xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 0):

If your API requires this, check out [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which creates string representations of NSDate objects in any way you want.  Just set the locale like this:

```
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
```

Here's [a good intro to this class at NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nsformatter/).

You may find it simpler, though, to change your API to accept the number of seconds since 1 January 1970, GMT as the date.  This is a common way to express date and time when transferring data between platforms.  You can call the `timeIntervalSince1970` method on your NSDate object to retrieve this data.  Then the API can translate it to a locale, or a time zone, if it needs to.